# functional space and norm corresponding to a kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to understand kernels but have a weak understanding of function spaces. Is there a simple explanation for why the following kernel has the given corresponding functional space and the norm? Is there a method of finding functional spaces and norms for other kernels , say a radial kernel?

Define a linear kernel function as

> $k(x,x')= x^Tx'$

on the vector space $X=R^P$

The corresponding functional space is the space of the linear function

> $f: R^d -> R: $
>
> $H= \lbrace f(x) = w^Tx : w \in R^p \rbrace $

and the associated norm is just the slope of the linear function

> $||f||_H=||w||$